# response to webpage with javascript in golang

Tags: javascript, html, go

I have a webpage with login and password forms
If login or password are wrong how could I response with javascript alert() or console.log() functions in golang

```
<body>
    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
          <form class="login-form"action="/login" method="POST">
            <input type="text"   name="username"   placeholder="username"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <button type="submit" id="send" value="Login">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

GOLANG

```
func (c *AuthenticationControllers) AdminLogin() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "C:/Projects/Go/src/github.com/AlifElectronicQueue/web/template/login.html")
        case "POST":

            //********AUTHENTICATION PROCESS*********//
            if loginAns {
                //Some code
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/admin/applications", 302)

            }  else {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", 302)
                http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusForbidden), http.StatusForbidden)
            }
```

Comment: In your Go code when the login fails, don't redirect and write the error response, you can do only one of those per request/response. Do you want to return StatusForbidden or 302? Choose one.

Comment: In your JS you can do what you want either by sending the request with javascript and waiting for the response and then based on the response do alert/log accordingly, or you can have the Go code redirect to a page where your JS already knows what to alert/log, or you re-render the login page but with some additional data, provided by Go, which is then read and handled by JS.

Comment: OK, It is clear, however I have another question.
How to response (wrong password or login) without refreshing the html page?
Because redirection refreshes the html page, what I should use instead?

Comment: In that case you can use the 1st option in my second comment. Send the form data with JS using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).